# MySQL Return Specific Dates

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a Table full of Videos and Video Post IDs. Some have the same Title but are reposted days later as the screenshot shows. Therefore, the same video has different Ids. If I need to retrieve Views within 7 days of the original Creation Date per Title no matter how many reposts have been made, how do I exclude additional days such as the last 3 rows in my post? Since the Creation Date is January 5, I only want views for January 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, and 12 in this case. The reason January 5 is not inclusive is because the video is usually posted one day after the Creation Date.

In some cases, I may have 3 reposts within 7 days of the original Creation Date. This example just has 1 repost for same Video.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8.0, you can do a window `min()` for this:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, min(creation_date) over(partition by title) first_creation_date
    from mytable t
) t
where total_days <= first_creation_date + interval 7 days
```

In earlier versions, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where total_days <= (
    select min(creation_date) + interval 7 days
    from mytable t1
    where t1.title = t.title
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much GMB!!! Overall, my SQL is good but one thing I never really learned was over(partition by ____). I am going to review this. Also, Total Days should have been "Filtered Date" in my screenshot. I originally was doing Count(Distinct Filtered Date) as "Total Days" to make sure I was pulling 7 days.